# How to kill all processes for a given user that take longer then X time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, command

When I list processes with `ps auxf` I often see some that are stuck and I need to manually kill them. How can I do it with one command?

Example ps result:

```
$ ps auxf
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME     COMMAND
tommass   7971 62.3  1.1 316428 45844 ?        R    Aug08 29133:14  xxxxxxxx
tommass   7978  0.0  2.6 455072 105964 ?       S    Aug08   8:56    xxxxxxxx
tommass   7979  0.0  2.6 454436 105360 ?       S    Aug08   8:57    xxxxxxxx
tommass  15034 67.8  1.1  51828 43760 ?        R    Aug14 26411:38  xxxxxxxx
tommass   7982  0.0  2.6 455012 105904 ?       S    Aug08   8:28    xxxxxxxx
```

1. How can I kill all processes for a given user "tommass" that take longer then 1 hour
2. How can I kill all processes for a given user "tommass" whose STAT is "R"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer 1), start with

```
ps -u tomass -o pid,time
```

(depending on you context, you may wish to select time (cpu time), etime (elapsed time))

to answer 2), try

```
ps -u tomass -o state,pid | awk '$1 == "R" { printf "kill %d\n",$2 ;}' | ksh
```

You really want to kill Running process ?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to go about this.

1. Set a CPU time limit on user processes using pam_limits.so and `/etc/secrity/limits.conf`. This will cause processes that go over their CPU time quota to receive an XCPU signal; if they don't specifically block/ignore/handle it, it will cause them to exit.
2. Use the [Auto Nice Daemon](http://and.sourceforge.net/) (`and` package on Debian/Ubuntu). It will renice and/or kill processes that use too much CPU time.
3. It should be possible to hack up a script that calls `ps(1)` with a format string argument that causes it to print only the fields you care about (i.e. cpu time, username, pid), then process that output using a shellscript like `grep -f file-with-one-username-per-line | while read cputime username pid; do [ "$cputime" -gt max-cpu-time ] && kill -9 $pid; done`, but this would be reinventing the Auto Nice Daemon.